# Poincare recurrence and the multiverse

Tags: cosmology, multiverse, instantons, string-theory-landscape, poincare-recurrence

In this [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0302219) Susskind claims that a stable de Sitter universe is problematic (among other things) due to the existence of Poincare recurrence, which happen because of finite entropy. I disagree that this is a problem for reasons similar to those given [here](http://motls.blogspot.com/2008/02/george-wing-poincare-recurrence.html). 
In any case, he also proposes a variant of eternal inflation driven by false vacuum decays. These decays, as far as I know, are driven by Coleman - de Luccia instantons and are probabilistic in nature, that is to say there is always some probability of instanton creation via quantum fluctuation.

My questions are:

1. Since false vacuum decay is probabilistic is it possible that in this bubble cosmology setup there are casual patches which live beyond their Poincare recurrence time?
2. Is there any possibility in string theory that our Universe, assuming it has finite entropy, will eventually be stabilized for an infinite amount of time or is this question settled beyond all reasonable doubt?

Comment: Where were you last week when the international frontiers in cosmology conference was happening? This would have been a great question! +1 but I can't really help you here.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know. I work in quantum information theory, not cosmology. I am just interested in the ultimate fate of the Universe.

Comment: The quoted blog entry, by Lubos Motl, seems to assume that there is only one possible relation between macro- and micro-states:  That might be true in our observable region, or even throughout a single universe, but to assume that it's prevalent everywhere seems unjustified, especially in view of the scale invariance in General Relativity and the possibility that reality might consist of a multiverse of causally-separated "local universes".  Consequently, between the OP's two references, I'd favor Susskind's.